# How to prevent tracking sensitive data in URLs?

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, sensitive-data, hotjar

Some URLs in my single-page-app (SPA) contain sensitive information like an access token, user information, etc.

Examples:

```
/callback#access_token=HBVYTU2Rugv3gUbvgIUY
/?email=username@example.com
```

I see that [hotjar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotjar) allows suppressing DOM elements and images from tracked data. Is it possible to hide params in URL or at least disable tracking for some pages?

Comment: Have you considered putting those data into request headers using AJAX?

Comment: Did you try putting, accessing that data through cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are saying that it is *your* SPA, you might solve the problem by switching from GET requests (which have the parameters inside the URL) to [POST requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)). I do not know hotjar, but if you tell the tracking service to analyze URLs only, that would be an option worth considering.

Another option frequently used is to [obfuscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) your parameters in the URL, see e.g. [Best way to obfuscate an e-mail address on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748780/best-way-to-obfuscate-an-e-mail-address-on-a-website) However, that is never a really safe solution for sensitive data, since the de-ciphering step is too easy, in particular if your man-in-the-middle has all requests ever send to your SPA.

**Edit.** I just found in the [Hotjar allows RegEx](https://help.hotjar.com/hc/en-us/articles/115012727628-How-to-Use-Regular-Expressions-for-Page-Targeting-and-IP-Blocking). Assuming you could enter a regular expression of URL-parts to exclude. 
The general syntax `/foo/bar/` means that `foo` should be replaced by `bar`, in our case, we want to delete the given snippet, that why it is `/foo//`.

For the given case of the access token, the regular expression would be

```
/callback#access_token=[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}//
```

and respectively for the email part of the URL

```
/\?email=(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]))\.){3}(?:(2(5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])//
```

This second RegEx partially taken from [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: It's a callback URL from 3-rd party service. I cannot change it. Having this token from the URL, someone can log in to the application.

Comment: I see the issue now. Can you use other tracking services?

Comment: @TarasHupalo I just had another idea how to tackle your issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that it's reasonable to assume that tracking scripts will try to access `window.location.href` or similar to get the current url which they will store.

So a possible solution would be create a dynamic scope which has a different value for `window.location.href` (with all sensitive info filtered out)

This is how it might work:

```js
// get the tracker script as a string, so you can eval it in a dynamic scope

let trackerScript = 'console.log("Tracked url:", window.location.href)';

// now lets lock it up
function trackerJail(){
  let window = {
    location: {
      // put your filtered url here
      href: "not so fast mr.bond"
    }
  }
  
  eval(String(trackerScript))
}

trackerJail()
```

If the tracking snippet is wrapped in a function it might be possible to create a dynamic scope for it without running `eval` by overriding it's prototype instead. But I'm not sure you can count on tracker scripts being wrapped in a neat function you can modify.

Also, there are a couple more ways the script might try to access the URL, so make sure to cover all the exits

Comment: (Unaffiliated) Reminds me of figmas sandboxing system: https://www.figma.com/blog/how-we-built-the-figma-plugin-system/

Answer (score 2):

If you control the page and order of scripts, you could read the data from the url then delete it before anything else can get to it.

*proofOfConcept.html*

```html
<script id="firstThingToLoad.js">
    console.log(window.location.href);
    const keyRegex = /key=[^&]*/;
    const key = window.location.href.match(keyRegex);
    console.log("I have key", key);

    const href = window.location.href.replace(keyRegex, "");
    history.replaceState({}, "", href);
</script>

<script id="someSnoopyCode.js">
    console.log("I'm snooping: ", window.location.href);
</script>

<body>
    <a href="/?key=secret">Link to private</a>
</body>
```

Of course the `Link to private` should not exist as is.  Also, this does break refresh and  most navigation in general, though there are ways to catch and save that.